# How can I receive a specific index of an validator array of array validation in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation

I validate an array in laravel controller and receive message by using ***$errors->first('field_name')*** or ***$errors*** or ***$errors->has('field_name)***. Now the problem is, I validate an array named vaccine_certificate and I can not receive the error message. Actually I receive the message when show all erros at once. but I want to show it with it's input area.  How can I solve it?

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'employee_no' => 'required',
         'vaccine_certificate.*' => 'image|mimes:png,jpg|max:2048|dimensions:max_height=200,max_width=200',
        //'expertise' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Input field looks like

```
<div class="col-6 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label " for="vaccine_certificate"><h5 class="h6">Vaccine Certificate <small>(<2mb,png,jpg) </small> </h5></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="vaccine_certificate[]" id="vaccine_certificate" multiple/>
                    @if ($errors->has('vaccine_certificate'))
                    <p id="employee_no_checker_message" class="text-danger p-2" onload="changeInputBorderColor('vaccine_certificate')"> {{ $errors->first('vaccine_certificate') }}</p>
                    @endif
                    
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and see all errors in the error bag of form.

```
$errors->all()
```

However, as far as I can see there is no "required" in vaccine_certificate, and your rule is vaccine_certificate.*, that means it should be an array. If you make it vaccine_certificate and required like you did in the name field you can see the error message.

If you need to use array, you can use:

```
$errors->first('vaccine_certificate.*')
```

Since it is not "required" it will not throw an error and you can not see it in the $errors variable.